# Webpage. Can't find element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Код:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open('https://www.google.com/', function(status) {
  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector('.hp vasq');
  });
  console.log(title);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Возвращает `null`, хотя элемент есть на странице и правильно называется.

`findElementsNyClassName()` так же не помогает.

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Может ибо нужно использовать `getElementsbyClassName`?

Comment: Это просто опечатка.